# How to get id of last purchase with multiple addresses?

Tags: magento, payment-gateway, payment

I have a payment method that needs to be redirected to the page it like paypal, I can add a code block on the page of success but need to know if petido that was just completed was paid with my payment method, so I can redirect.

Note: several people say it is not possible to redirect payments with multishipping.

I just want to get the id of the application of the current purchase being multishipping.

I got this way, but it's not exactly what I want:

```
$fromDate = date('Y-m-d') . ' 0:0:0';
$toDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$orderCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', array('eq' => array(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId())));
$orderCollection = $orderCollection->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from'=>$fromDate, 'to'=>$toDate));
foreach($orderCollection as $order_row){
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
$last_quote_id = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastQuoteId();
$orderCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', array('eq' => array(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId())));
$orderCollection = $orderCollection->addFilter('quote_id', $last_quote_id);
foreach($orderCollection as $order_row){
    if($order_row->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getTitle() == 'PagSeguro'){ $pagseguro = 1; }
    echo $order_row->getId() . ' - ' . $order_row->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getTitle() . '<br />';    
}
```